# Python (2.7), time.sleep, while loop, Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, time

I've been learning about using Threading and Time, because I want a few things to be happening in my script, each on its own time.

In the concrete example I want **FIR** to remove 2 from **TOT** every 0.5 seconds, while **SEC** also removes from **TOT**, but every 2.1 seconds. I've spend almost all day on this problem, reading around and trying out different things, but I am stuck!

```
import time
import threading

suma = {
  'fir': 2,
  'sec': 3,
  'tot': 80
}

def doCalc():
    time.sleep(2.1)       
    suma['tot'] = suma['tot'] - suma['sec']
    print 'second action: ' + str(suma['tot'])


while int(suma['tot']) > 0:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print 'first action: ' + str(suma['tot'])
    suma['tot'] = suma['tot'] - suma['fir']     
    for i in range(1):
        threading.Thread(target=doCalc).start()

time.sleep(3)       
print '_' * 10
```

Comment: Try starting *two* background threads instead of just one, and pass the sleep time and the amount to subtract as arguments to `doCalc`.  It's cleaner that way.  If instead you need to keep one of the actions in the main thread for some reason, move the creation and start of the background thread to before the beginning of the main `while` loop.

Comment: You may also want to look into use of locks to avoid race conditions.

Comment: You are creating too many threads. Move `threading.Thread(target=doCalc).start()` out of the loop or better do as Mark suggested.

Comment: You *absolutely* need add locks. This is extremely likely to cause to two threads to step on each other while changing the value of `suma['tot']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one version of the algorithm.  It starts two threads, then after a few seconds signals them to exit.  (You can't terminate Python threads, you have to ask them politely to exit.)  All writes to the shared dictionary are protected by a lock.

Thanks to @Mark, @dmitri, and @dano.

TODO: pass in args, as @mark suggested.

### source

```
import time
import threading

suma_lock = threading.Lock()
suma = {
  'fir': 2,
  'sec': 3,
  'tot': 80
}

def doCalc():
    time.sleep(2.1)
    with suma_lock:
        suma['tot'] -= suma['sec']
    print 'second action: ' + str(suma['tot'])

def first():
    while int(suma['tot']) > 0:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print 'first action: ' + str(suma['tot'])
        with suma_lock:
            suma['tot'] -= suma['fir']     

threading.Thread(target=first).start()
threading.Thread(target=doCalc).start()

time.sleep(3)       
print '_' * 10

# hack: tell 'first' to exit
with suma_lock:
    suma['tot'] = 0

for thread in threading.enumerate():
    if thread != threading.current_thread():
        thread.join()
print 'DONE'
```

### output

```
first action: 80
first action: 78
first action: 76
first action: 74
second action: 69
first action: 69
__________
first action: 0
DONE
```